# Does MySQL provide native support for enabling a resilient data storage?

Tags: mysql

My client strongly desires for a *highly availability* access to data stored in their MySQL database. They want to be confident that a reliable solution exists to avert downtime due  to a database server failure.

In the scope of MySQL database, how may I provide a resilient data storage solution to my clients?

There should be a means to ensure our app stays up and is not starved of data necessity for its operation when DB server goes down. I googled and found this:
http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/configuration.html

But I think there should be an easier way to switch between different DB servers, am I right?

In any case my question is: what is the practices to handle such situations when DB server goes offline?

Comment: its called replication

Comment: One major reason why cloud services are popular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the challenge you described is [Database Replication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_(computing)#Database_replication).

> Replication in computing involves sharing information so as to ensure consistency between redundant resources, such as software or hardware components, to improve reliability, fault-tolerance, or accessibility.
>
> Database replication can be used on many database management systems (DBMS), usually with a master-slave relationship between the original and the copies. The master logs the updates, which then ripple through to the slaves. Each slave outputs a message stating that it has received the update successfully, thus allowing the sending of subsequent updates.

MySQL supports DB replication when you configure it. So, you do not have to implement the actual replication process.

See the official MySQL documentation on ⇢ [MySQL database replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html).

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a database cluster (probably with multi-master replication)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-cluster-replication-multi-master.html

This topic is WAY too deep for an SO post, but this is the direction you should be heading.